# How can I direct Javascript to access the second element with a non-unique ID

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to declare a paired list in my automation framework, and to do so I pass in two parameters of that list. The first parameter is the DOM id of the "Available" items list, while the second is the DOM id of the "Selected" items list.

```
var pairedList: newPairedList( "availableItemsListID" , "selectedItemsListID");
```

In the specific case I'm working on, both the availableItemsListID and the selectedItemsListID happen to have the same ID in the DOM.

The both ids are 'x-fieldset-bwrap', and I have tried the following to indicate the availableItemsListID is the first instance of the id, and the selectedItemsListID is the second instance of the id:

```
var pairedList: newPairedList( "/x-fieldset-bwrap/[0]" , "/x-fieldset-bwrap/[1]");
```

It seems to find the availableItemsList however when it attempts to get the selectedItemsList it fails. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to best handle the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: best handle is to make IDs unique, the page is in fact broken

Comment: I understand this however I am not in a position in which I can change the IDs.

Comment: can you change how newPaireList works ? Also email your boss that this will bring down the production environment sooner or later unless the IDs are changed (just to keep your arse safe)

Comment: Yes I can change how newPairedList works however it would cause a decent amount of rework in a variety of other written tests and declarations of various other paired lists, so that would not be ideal. Do you know of any way to indicate the second record by chance? I agree with you that we need to make the IDs unique and this wouldn't be an issue, however that is not a possibility for my position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can distinguish the first element from the second one somehow, then you can use that difference in your selection. See below:

```js
 function display($div) {
  console.log($div.html());
}

display($('#unique'));
$('#unique').addClass('firstUnique');
display($('#unique:not(.firstUnique)'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="unique">One</div>
<div id="unique">Two</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all elements that match a CSS selector.

`document.querySelectorAll("#x-fieldset-bwrap")` will match all elements with a `id` of `x-fieldset-bwrap`.

If you have the ability to change your system so that it does not generate elements with repeated IDs concurrently within the DOM, I would highly encourage you to do so.